# Possible to use sqllite in its own container?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, docker, ecmascript-6

I am building an app in Express, where the db load is minimal, so going with something such as Postgres or MongoDB would be overkill. So I were thinking of using sqlite.

## Question

Is it possible to separate sqlite into its own container, while the app lives in another container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is not meant to be daemonized. It's a flat file database. There is really no point in running it in its own container because there is nothing to run. The usual usage is putting the sqlite database in a volume.

A quick Google suggests people have been daemonizing it[1] but that's just additional complexity which is better done by Postgres anyway.

[1] http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/sqlite-in-a-daemon-td31298.html

Comment: Is it correct that sqlite only communicates over a socket?

Comment: Usually you "communicate" with SQLite by making direct library calls; there's no "socket" or "daemon" or anything else.

Comment: As @DavidMaze mentioned, there is no socket. A socket implies that there is a process on the receiving end listening to your requests. The simplest analogy I can make here is that SQLite is like a file. You don't write lines to a file using sockets or something. You open the file, write, and close. That's all there is too it.